# Python regex for float dash float

Tags: python, regex

if i want to find every odds which has the following format - ( 1.64 - 2.38), how do i code regex?

```
 <td class="t-odds">
       1.64 - 2.38                 
      </td>

 re.findall(r'bets/.+?/.+?">(.+?)</a>',Tennis)
```

Comment: Incomplete code. I failed to find an anchor tag. What's the value of variable `Tennis`?

Comment: You look like you're trying to use regex to parse HTML - don't. Use an HTML parser!

Comment: This problem becomes much more difficult if you want to match the representation of _all_ possible floats, such as `1e-10` and `nan`

Comment: [People have gone insane](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/103081) over parsing HTML with regex code.

Comment: I can't tell what the format is from this snippet.  Is the td class name always "t-odds"?  Could the odds be displayed as plain text instead of a table cell? The currently posted `re.findall` call doesn't provide any hints of what you want to do, either, though it should.  The title says "float dash float" but there is no dash in the `re.findall`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably this regex: `(\d+\.\d+)\s\-\s(\d+.\d+)`

But honestly, as @jonrsharpe and others have suggested in comments, what you should do is use an HTML parser. Not only is it safer, it is easier.

You can try a live demo of my regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/pK5vD9/1), on Regex101.com.